# update maintenance date in customer table from the latest date in service table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-update, relational-database

Customers

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| recno | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| CustomerKey | int | NO |  | NULL |  |
| MaintDate | date | YES |  | NULL |  |

Service Orders

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| recno | int | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| CustomerKey | int | NO |  | NULL |  |
| ServiceDate | date | YES |  | NULL |  |

Customers has one record per customer. Service Orders has multiple records per customer.

How do I `UPDATE Customers` to update each Customers MaintDate record with the record in Service Orders with the newest ServiceDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grouped join is likely more efficient than the subquery plus `EXISTS`, as that answer looks up the child table twice.

```sql
UPDATE Customers c
JOIN (
    SELECT
      so.CustomerKey,
      MAX(SERVICE_DATE) AS MaxDate
    FROM ServiceOrders so
    GROUP BY so.CustomerKey
) so ON so.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey 
SET c.MaintDate = so.MaxDate;
```

Having said that, I would advise you *not* to denormalize like this, and instead just query the child table when needed, unless such a query is particularly inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for this follow up. This query actually just needed to be run one time to get the Customers table to where it could be updated when needed.

Comment: This query actually worked. The other answer wiped half of the records in the Customers table. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffForrester In case of all nulls in SERVICE_DATE column of SERVICE_ORDERS  table this will put null in MAINT_DATE column too. You should handle that null.

Comment: In case of all nulls in SERVICE_DATE column of SERVICE_ORDERS table, it is desirable that MAIN_DATE be set to null, so this worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

With sample data as:

```sql
Create Table CUSTOMERS (REC_NO INT, CUST_KEY INT, MAINT_DATE DATE);

Insert Into CUSTOMERS 
  Select 1, 100, DATE '2023-12-01' From Dual Union All
  Select 2, 200, DATE '2023-12-10' From Dual Union All
  Select 3, 300, DATE '2023-12-20' From Dual 

Select * From CUSTOMERS
/*
REC_NO  CUST_KEY    MAINT_DATE
    1       100     2023-12-01
    2       200     2023-12-10
    3       300     2023-12-20      */
```

```sql
Create Table SERVICE_ORDERS (REC_NO INT, CUST_KEY INT, SERVICE_DATE DATE);

Insert Into SERVICE_ORDERS 
  Select 1, 100, DATE '2023-12-02' From Dual Union All
  Select 2, 100, DATE '2023-12-12' From Dual Union All
  Select 3, 200, DATE '2023-12-15' From Dual Union All
  Select 4, 300, DATE '2023-12-28' From Dual Union All
  Select 5, 300, DATE '2024-01-04' From Dual Union All
  Select 6, 300, DATE '2024-01-11' From Dual 

Select * From SERVICE_ORDERS
/*
REC_NO  CUST_KEY    SERVICE_DATE
    1       100     2023-12-02
    2       100     2023-12-12
    3       200     2023-12-15
    4       300     2023-12-28
    5       300     2024-01-04
    6       300     2024-01-11      */
```

U p d a t e :

```sql
UPDATE CUSTOMERS c 
SET c.MAINT_DATE = (Select Max(SERVICE_DATE) 
                    From SERVICE_ORDERS 
                    Where CUST_KEY = c.CUST_KEY
                   )
WHERE EXISTS (Select 1 From SERVICE_ORDERS Where CUST_KEY = c.CUST_KEY)
```

Check the result:

```sql
Select * From CUSTOMERS
/*
REC_NO  CUST_KEY    MAINT_DATE
    1       100     2023-12-12
    2       200     2023-12-15
    3       300     2024-01-11      */
```

Comment: Upon further examination, I noticed that this query wiped about half of the records in the Customers database. Any idea why that would have happened?

Comment: @JeffForrester What exactly does it meaan "wiped"? If it means deleted rows then it DID NOT. If it is null value in MAINT_DATE column of your CUSTOMERS table after update - then it did in case that the CUST_KEY that has rows in SERVICE_ORDERS table and NONE of those rows has a SERVICE_DATE recorded. That you should handle the null value returned by select statement or add the condition in EXISTS clause ruleing out the rows without SERVICE_DATE. Question neither mention such a possibility nor your sample data has that isssue. We don't know your data. There's a question and sample data provided.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It actually took existing records and set the values to NULL, like Firstname, Lastname, etc. I can't explain why. I only know that it did. I used the exact example above, only substituting the actual tables name and fields.

Comment: @JeffForrester That just could not be true that SET column1 = whatever results as SET column2 = Null. . It is something else for sure...

Comment: I totally agree. I'm just telling you what happened. The query in the other answer took a half second. This query took nearly five minutes, like it was stuck in a loop, so it might have timed out.

Comment: @JeffForrester The fact is that my answer is slower and that the other one should have been accepted, but that is not the issue here. The issue is your first comment saying '...this query wiped about half of records ...'  which is simply not true in any way imaginable.